# Using a pointer member of a pointer member object as the argument of a function

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, member

Basically what I want is a function which can access all of the elements of *b.x[i].var (i being arbitrary and the * is there since "var" is a pointer itself).

This is possible in the case that an ordinary pointer like

```
double * point = new double [N]
```

was called by something like

```
double func (double * p){
  return p[2];
}
```

but seem difficult to generalize to the case of class pointer members that are themselves objects with pointer members and I have been unable to find a explanation of how to do it properly (please forgive me if I don't get the nomenclature right - this is all still somewhat new to me).

To be more specific I have produced a simplified code to illustrate the issue:

```
class A {
public:
  double * var = new double;
};

class B {
  int N;
public:
  B (int, int);
  A * x = new A[N];
};

B::B (int d, int V) {
  N = d*V;
}

double func (double * a){
  return a[2];
}

int main () {

  int d = 3, V = 4;

  B b (d,V);

  *b.x[2].var = 1.2;

  cout << func(b.x.var) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

where I had hoped that the output would be 1.2 but non-surprisingly it does not compile. It strikes me that the a[2] in the function as well as the b.x.var are likely wrong but despite my efforts I have been unable to realize the correct syntax.

Eventually I want to generalize the pointer var to be double * var = new double [n] and it would be great if any solution offered could work in this case as well.

As an alternative I tried giving the input A * a in the function and a return *a[2].var and then calling the function with func(b.x) but while compiling alright it gives a "segmentation faul 11".

Finally I realize that I could just work with one (or no) class but that would just be a circumvention of the problem, not a solution.

Any insights or solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I hope you realize `A * x = new A[N];` uses `N` while it's uninitialized.

Comment: also, `x[2]` returns a *pointer* to `A`, so it should be *(b.x[2]->var) [little bit easier for me to read...]

Comment: You may use `std::vector` instead of raw owning array.

Comment: @Nim x[1] will not return a pointer, it will return a reference to the A at index 1 from x

Comment: @chris I did not. Neither did I know that it had to be moved to the constructor for it to work properly. That issue is now fixed - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do but here is something that compiles and returns valid data, with inline comments:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  double * var = new double;
};

class B {
  int N;
public:
  B (int, int);
  A * x; // you can't initialize with N here
};

B::B (int d, int V) {
  N = d*V;
  x = new A[N]; // initialize here instead when N is defined
}

double func (A *a){
  int i = 0;
  return *(a[i].var);
}

int main () {

  int d = 3, V = 4;

  B b(d,V);

  //this value is accessed by func, make sure it has a value
  *(b.x[0].var) = 2.2;

  cout << func(b.x) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Updated code after OP's comments

Comment: Thank you for correcting the initialization of the x pointer - did not realize that it needed to be moved to the constructor.
The code works but does not achieve what I hoped. Basically I wanted a construction where I could call b.x[i].var within the function (i being specified only within the function, not in the argument as with your construction). Hope this makes the intention clearer?

Comment: something like the current state?

Comment: Yes, that fix would work! But here you went all the way 'out' to use b as an input - how come it does not work using b.x? (I will mark your answer as accepted afterwards - not sure if you can alter the code after I have accepted it as an answer)

Comment: Updated to allow b.x to be what you send to func, notice it's not accepting a pointer to A then uses that pointer as an array (which will have d*V instances.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues with the code:

```
class A {
    public:
      double * var = new double;
};
```

1. What is var?
2. You cannot initialize data inside a class like this (Use a constructor)

Comment: 1: I don't understand the question. It is a pointer-type member of the class A referring to a double? If you mean the value then I specify it in one instance in `*b.x[2].var = 1.2;`?
2: Thank you. I was not under the impression that this constituted an initialization (and as such belonged in the constructor). No errors or warnings seemed to pop up when compiling (although I realize that this is a necessary, not sufficient requirement for it to be correct).